# Python: How to add line break when using GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, text, newline, mesa

I want to print information to a gui and am using a public [framework](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/tree/main/examples/schelling) so my choices are limited.  I would like to update a function in [this page](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/blob/main/examples/schelling/server.py) so I can print to the gui.  Using the python print() function sends the output to the command line so I cannot use it.  The current framework uses a TextElement object that prints to the gui, however it prints a mass of text to the gui if I continue to add variables and starts to look sloppy:

```
def render(self, model):
    return ("Happy agents: " + str(model.happy)
    return ("# Agents in majority: %s \
            \n # Agents in minority: %s " 
     (model.countMajority, 
     model.countMinority ))
```

I added \n for line breaks but they are not adding new lines as I expected.  I saw suggestions in stack overflow with tkinter but it is not a library in this framework.  Do you have any suggestions how I can add a line break?

Thank you

Comment: Treatment of line breaks in UIs is generally platform-dependent.

Comment: I thought new line \n would be standard in most languages ( I thought it would be a non issue).  Is there an alternative to \n I can try?   I am using a windows system and follow the instructions here:  https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/blob/main/examples/schelling/README.md

Comment: This renders to a browser.  You might try `return "# Agents in majority: %s<br># Agents in minority: %s" % (model.countMajority, model.countMinority)`

Comment: It's not the *language,* it's the *platform.*

Comment: Right.  "\n" is a C invention, adopted by Python and Perl (and others), but it is certainly not universal.  HTML does not use it.

Comment: Thank you Tim Roberts! A simple <br> worked!  That makes sense considering it is the interface but the code had no HTML formatting references, so I did not consider that option.